# Chrome DevTools: Understanding the Initiator

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to understand the `initiator` column in Google Chrome Dev.

When I visit facebook.com, in the initiator column I see this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43b5h.png).
When you hold `shift` and hover over the requests, the parent of requests will be marked as green. However, in my observed case, the `Request X` and `Request Y` are not presented as parents, although they are in the initiator call stack.

I have here some understanding questions:

1. Am I missing something? Don't the requests in the initiator represent a chain that initialized the corresponding request?
2. Is it possible to get the sequences of the URLs in an initiator row If there are multiple entries.
3. Another problem there is the sequences seem very strange. For example, the Request `3c64zuZPF4s.js` appears in very different sequences multiple times. Why?